# Meteor mongo insert unique document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a simple Tags Collection in Meteor. Currently in order to ensure that a user cannot create a duplicate Tag document I do this:

```
var existingTag = Tags.findOne({name: "userInput"})
```

If existingTag is undefined then I can go ahead and do the insert.

Is there a better/correct way of doing this utilizing meteor mongodb syntax? Cant seem to find any documentation on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is to create Mongo index at the unique field. That way you'll have the uniqueness validation at Mongo level, as well as performance increase for searches on that field.

Meteor currently doesn't support index creation directly, so you need to manually log in to your database and add your index from there. The command for this is:

```
db.tags.ensureIndex({name: 1}, {unique: true})
```

[Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) you can find more information.

Comment: Actually, I think you can add the index from meteor with `Tags._ensureIndex('name', {unique: true})` but that interface is obviously subject to change. I've always done it from mongo directly.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something like in Rails `find_or_create_by_name` but this will work :-).

Comment: Meteor does contain something similar to `find_or_create_by_name`. it's called `Upsert` - https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert

Comment: @AyrtonSenna As for the `upsert` thing, yes, but.. that's a no go on the client. [See this posting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004772/uncaught-error-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id)  On the client, you can create a `varFind = myCollection.findOne` ... if  varFind exists, then  `update`, else `insert`