# Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I have this error but it does not specify which code line is faulty. 
Is there any way I can narrow down which codes I need to focus on?

Not sure if its a related problem, but when I submit a doc and its supposed to recognize my `user.username`, but it comes out blank when html displays `{{author}}`.

The code for the collection (shared folder for both public/ server) is as below:

```
var post = _.extend(postAttributes, {
  userId: user._id, 
  author: user.username
});
```

[image: This is the error message image]

Do appreciate any help!

**Update:**

New error message after shifting the UserAccount codes into server folder. 
`Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'postInsert'`
`"Match error: Unknown key in field message"`
[image]

Comment: _"I have this error but it does not specify which code line is faulty."_ Then why is it pointing at `mongo.js:472`? It's telling you exactly what line is faulty.

Comment: @Cerbrus Apologies for the missing lines, have attached them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have code on the client side that uses something that isn't an `_id` as its query operator to update a document.

It is not possible to update on the client with a query like this. You can do these on the server though.

So if you have code like this somewhere, you run it without throwing the error you're getting:

```
MyCollection.update({ someName: someValue }, {$set:{something:true}});
```

You can do this though:

```
var doc = MyCollection.findOne({ someName: someValue });
MyCollection.update({ _id: doc._id }, {$set:{something:true}});
```

Here you explicitly define which document you would like to update. To find this code you might want to look for anything with `.update` in it that can run on the client side.

Comment: @Thinkerer yes this is probably the line causing it. It only needs to run on the server. If you move it from the shared folder to the server folder it should solve the issue. The client would still get access to these records without any trouble since they are published by the accounts-* modules.

Comment: @Thinkerer the ones in config.js, 130-138 on the screenshot.

Comment: I think it works. The error message is gone, however still cant recognise {{author}} and theres new error. Have pasted it above.

Comment: @Thinkerer this is a unrelated issue to the original. For this one you have code in a client side `Meteor.methods` that has a `check` method in it. You are running this method with a document containing `message`. You don't have this defined in the `check` method hence it is throwing this error.

Comment: @Thinkerer on your screenshot. `postAttributes` has a `message` in it, yet your `check` has has `title` and `uri`, but not `message`.

Answer (score 2):

> **Changes to allow/deny rules**
>
> Starting in 0.5.8, client-only code such as event handlers may only update or remove a single document at a time, specified by _id. Method code can still use arbitrary Mongo selectors to manipulate any number of documents at once. To run complex updates from an event handler, just define a method with Meteor.methods and call it from the event handler.

Hope this helps :)