# How to update document of particular user id

Tags: meteor

Basically what I want to do is, just  update user details.so when
I input user ID all the other details of user are displayed in 
textbox. Then I can edit anything.

Below is my js code:

```
   Template.body.onCreated(function() {
        this.currentTextBox = new ReactiveVar();
   });

   Template.body.events({
       "keyup .new-task1"(event, instance) {
            instance.currentTextBox.set(event.target.value);
       }
   });

   Template.body.helpers({
       dbs() {
           const instance = Template.instance();
           return Dbs.find({'user_id':instance.currentTextBox.get()});
       }
   });

   Template.temp.events({
   "submit .sub"(event) {
       const target= event.target;
       const name1 =target.name.value;
       const add1 =add.value;   
       const r1 = target.r.value;
       const const1 = target.const.value;
       console.log(doc_id1);
       Dbs.update({"user_id" : "pid"},{"name" : "name1","r" : "r1","const" 
       : "const"}); 
   }
   });
```

Now the problem is I am not able to update the edited field, though the value of edited field is sent to js file from html.anyone help me to solve this issue as I am new to meteor and mongo db.

Html code:

```
  <head>
  <title>eg1</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
  rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

 <body>
 <nav class="#e57373 red lighten-2">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
 <a href="#" class="brand-logo">hello</a>
   <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   </nav>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col s2">

    <form class="new-task">
    <input type="text" name="pid" placeholder="patient_id" class="new-
    task1"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4">
    <ul class="collection">
    {{#each dbs}}
    {{>temp}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul><br><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

    <template name="temp">
    <li class="collection-item">
    <form class="sub">
    <input type="text" name="user_id" value=" {{user_id}}"/>          
    <input type="text" name="addd" value=" {{add}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="r" value=" {{r}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="const" value=" {{const}}"/>

    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="waves-effect 
    #607d8b grey btn"></center>
    </form>
    </li>
    </template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update a Mongo.db collection in meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090040/how-to-update-a-mongo-db-collection-in-meteor-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Meteor :)

You have to use `$set` attribute when you are updating document,

use as below and let me know.

```
Dbs.update({"user_id" : "pid"},{$set:{"name" : "name1","r" : "r1","const" : "const"}});
```

For more info on Collection.update [Click Here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update).

Also go through [Mongo Update Query example](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/update/) to know how to update a document when you directly use mongo shell.

Remember there are few differences when you directly use ***Mongo Shell commands*** and ***Meteor Collections***.

Comment: I have added my html code also pls tell me is it correct way to write .

Comment: @Nisha: Please format your code properly. It is hard to read and Yes! the code is correct. You may use it that way. By the way if my answer helped you achieve your solution, kindly accept the answer. To verify your html is yet another question :)

Comment: errorClass {isClientSafe: true, error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.", details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", …} i am getting above error.

Comment: @Nisha: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004772/uncaught-error-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id.

Comment: Thanks @Ankur Soni.the links that u suggested were helpful to solve the above issue.its working properly.Now next thing i want to do is, i want to display user details when i enter user ID in url.is there any way to do it ?

Comment: @Nisha: there is always a way to do anything as you are asking. post this as another question on Stackoverflow. I will try to answer it and many other masterminds will help you there. Always try to find your question first on Stackoverflow and create new if it does not exist.